# Install test and production outlook addin at same time

Tags: testing, outlook-addin

I have a pretty complex outlook addin that we have developed for our company.

The same users that use it in production are also the testers.

This leads to a lot of confusion and frustration as they have to uninstall the production version to test and then reinstall the production version when done testing.  This is error prone as sometimes they forget to uninstall the test version.  Also, The automatic updater will pick up the test version and install it on the non-testing user's outlook.

I would like the following:

1. Allow both test and production builds of the addin to be installed on the same person's outlook at the same time.
2. Use a different icon for the test version; perhaps just overlay "test" on the icon.

The addin communicates to web service so the test version will have to know to switch to the test URL.

What is a graceful way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**You will be able to install same outlook addin twice:**

1) By changing the AssemblyInfo.cs Title, Product and it's Guid.

```
e.g.

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("AddIn1")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("AddIn1")]

[assembly: Guid("d85cd50b-7e2f-4214-beaa-10698acdf6ed")]
```

2) You will also need to change the Assembly name from Application tab.

So by making two different projects with different icons loaded and with different assembly name you will be able to achieve this.

Comment: Because AssemblyInfo.cs is a .cs file is it possible to add an if statement in the file that will detect if the build is Release or Debug and switch automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler csc.exe and the C# language itself do not expose any predefined constants for conditional compilation. Visual Studio only adds the `DEBUG` and `TRACE` values, which can be configured through the IDE. The IDE also lets you add your own arbitrary symbols, but since these are essentially fixed (invariant) values, the capability is of limited use.

You can use conditional compilation in the following way - the DEBUG configuration can be used for testing the add-in:

```
#if DEBUG
   [assembly: AssemblyTitle("TestAddin")]
   [assembly: AssemblyProduct("TestAddin")]
   [assembly: Guid("d85ca54b-7e1f-4214-beaa-10694acda6ed")]
#else
   [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ReleaseAddin")]
   [assembly: AssemblyProduct("ReleaseAddin")]
   [assembly: Guid("d85cd50b-7e2f-4214-beaa-10698acdf6ed")]
#endif
```

Read more about assembly attributes in the [Set assembly attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes) article.

Comment: Is the DEBUG variable added when I choose the Debug build option in VS?  If so that would be quite handy way to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, it is. There is no need to define anything.